# detecting a character in file and splitting the byte arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an array of bytes that I need to read from a file. I have to detect a character(basically an identifier telling me that what follows is a new set of data). So whenever I see this character I have to copy it into a new array. My idea was to have a 2D array and another size_t array which corresponds to size of each of these arrays. However, I realize that there is some problem where I have defined the sizes. Is this a good way to realize this? Why does it not show the desired behaviour then?

Do throw some light.

```
int ret = 1;
int i, j  = 0;
FILE *fp = NULL;
const char *filename = "arrOfBytes"
fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (fp == NULL)
    return -1;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
int size = ftell(fp); 
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
char *arr[size];
size_t *arrSz;
arrSz = (size_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(size_t));
int ch;
size_t len = 0;
printf("size = %lu\n", size);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
// 68 65 6c 6c 6f 63 68 65 6c 6c 63 68 65 78 ---> detect ascii c= 63 hex value
    arr[i] = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!arr[i]) return -1;
    //if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && (len != size)){
        if (ch != 'c'){
            arr[i][len++]=ch;
            //printf("arr [%d][%d]  = %02X\n ", i, len -1 , arr[i][len -1]); 
        }
        arrSz[i] = len;
        arr[i] = realloc(arr[i], sizeof(char)*(len));//size is start size
        printf("arrSz[%d] = %d\n", i, arrSz[i]);
        printf("len = %d\n", len);
        printf("arr[%d][arrSz[%d]]= %d\n", i,arrSz[i], arr[i][(*arrSz)[i]]);
    }
    arr[i][len++]='\0';

}
fclose(fp);
```

Update here is what I have:

```
// 68 65 6c 6c 6f 63 68 65 6c 6c 63 68 65 78

//identify 63 (character 'c')

//array 0: 68 65 6c 6c 6f   (arrSize 0 = 5)
//array 1: 68 65 6c 6c      (arrSize 1 = 4)
//array 2: 68 65 78         (arrSize 2 = 3)

//arrayCount = 0+1+2 = 3


int ret = 1;
int i, j  = 0;
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
if (fp == NULL)
    return -1;
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
int size = ftell(fp); 
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
char **array;
size_t *arrSz;
array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*));
arrSz = (size_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(size_t));
int ch;
int arrayCount = 0;
size_t len = 0;
printf("size = %lu\n", size);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){

    arrayCount++;
    array = realloc(array,(arrayCount * sizeof(char*)));
    array[i] = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!array[i]) return -1;

    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && (len != size) && ((char)ch != 'c'))
    {

        array[i][len++]=(char)ch;

    }
    arrSz[i] = len;
    array[i] = realloc(array[i], sizeof(char)*(len));//size is start size
    if(len == 0 | array[i] == NULL)
        break;
    printf("arrSz[%d] = %d\n", i, arrSz[i]);
    printf("len = %d\n", len);
    len = 0; //reset len counter

}

fclose(fp);
printf("new size of array = %d\n", sizeof(array));

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < arrSz[i]; j++){

        printf("array [%d][%d]  = %02X\n ", i, j , array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Even after re-allocating the array, I see that the size it returns is 8 :(
I have 2 unknowns here:
number of bytes of data each array will have. 
Number of arrays itself. This is why I went for a 2D array.

Comment: Why is this post being down voted?

Comment: "Is this a good way to realize this?" is not a good question, since that's imprecise and subjective. Reviews of working code should be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, if you do have a problem you do not tell how it manifests itself. A question about a problem in the code should include the current behavior and the desired behavior. You should also include any warnings or error messages.

Comment: OK thanks. I will improve the question

Comment: Don't modify your existing code. That renders existing answers wrong. Only do this for obvious typos and such. This is a Q/A. Not an interative help to improve your code. I have rolled back your post.

Comment: But please do the other changes you made.

Answer (score 1):

One major problem is this:

```
size_t **arrSz;
*arrSz = (size_t *)malloc(size * sizeof(size_t));
```

Here you dereference the pointer `arrSz` before it's initialized. That will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It's also not clear why you want a pointer-to-pointer, which could be working as a jagged array of arrays of `size_t` values. And you don't need an array of arrays of lengths.

Later you also do

```
*arrSz[i] = len;
```

which in conjunction with the above code is wrong since you attempt to initialize `arrSz` as a pointer to an array, not an array of pointers, which means you should have done `(*arrSz)[i] = len`. But since `arrSz` is still uninitialized it's still UB no matter what you do.

The simple solution? Don't use double-indirection (pointer to pointer):

```
size_t *arrSz = malloc(sizeof *arrSz * size);
```

---

There are also many other problems, like for example you not resetting `len` once you have read one string, meaning the next iteration of the `for` loop you will continue with the previous value and have uninitialized data at the beginning of the memory you allocate.

I also suggest you [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically how to use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, and see how the values change.

Comment: Hi, you are right. I corrected it. But that is not the problem. I see that the allocation to character is 1 but the fgetc returns an int and there is a "resizing" problem which I am stuck with :(

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the "len" reset. I had overlooked it and no wonder was getting into nirvana :)